# Seeding an ActiveRecord Database with objects from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to Rails, I'm making my first app and I have (another) question:

I'm adding a "decks of cards" feature to my flashcard app, but having trouble with the modeling to generate a "deck" that is populated by card objects from my card table.

Here are my associations:

```
User has_many :decks

Deck belongs_to :user
Deck has_many :cards

Card belongs_to :deck




class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deck

  validates :front, presence: true
  validates :back, presence: true
  validates :deck_id, presence: true

end
```

And here's my decks migration/table:

```
class Decks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :decks do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :card
      t.integer :user_id, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My issue is that I would like for the "card" column in the decks table to consist of Card objects, so that I can access/manipulate their methods, but I'm not sure how exactly to do this. I tried populating the table with t.string of ":card" in the hopes that this would work but it only comes up blank. I am wondering if this is even possible or advisable or is there a better way?

If anyone can point me to resources/offer advice on this, thank you. I checked the docs/SO and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing can be easily accomplished.

Provided that `User`, `Deck` and `Card` are **ActiveRecord** models, you can associate them by setting foreign keys to connect the tables. A foreign key is an `integer` column that contains the `id` of the associated model (its table's primary key)

The Rails convention is to use `belongs_to` and `has_many` to declare "one to many" associations ([docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)). These methods will add to your model objects the required methods to represent and interact with the association.

On the DB schema side of things, you'll need to set the foreign keys on the models' tables that declare the `belongs_to` associations.

So, if you have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :decks
end

class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :cards
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deck
end
```

You'll need these migrations:

```
class CreateDecks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :decks do |t|
      # your other columns...
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end
end

class CreateCards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cards do |t|
      # your other columns...
      t.integer :deck_id
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With a has_many relation you don't store the foreign key on the owning table. Instead you have a `deck_id` column in the cards table.

An example of using an association:

```
# Load a deck and include the cards in the query
@deck = Deck.joins(:cards).last

@deck.cards.each do |card|
  puts card.front
end

# create a new card
@deck.cards.new(front: 'foo', back: 'bar')
@deck.save # will save the card as well.
```

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the `card` column in your decks table. The `has_many :cards` and `belongs_to :deck` lines in your models provide that functionality for you to be able to do things like `@deck.cards`.

You just have to be sure to assign a deck_id when you create a new Card object.

You should read through the Rails Guides on [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), and also on [database seeding](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data).

Comment: thanks everyone for the explanations.... i had assigned a deck_id to my cards model by following the docs, but did not understand that this was enough to be able to have all access to cards methods via expressions like @deck.cards. seeded my database though and it works. thanks